# Troubleshooting Tomcat Deployment Issues with WAR Files"

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, war

I am trying to deploy my application to Tomcat and using the war file. I have extended application with springboot servelet and also add the tag in the property and started the external Tomcat. After that even my Tomcat is extracting my file and while I am trying to run it I am getting page not found. Please help me out.

I am expecting if anyone can guide me through it that would be great please.

Comment: Welcome. Please read how to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask